# Choosing a metric for lightGBM classifier (mean average precision k)

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, boosting, average-precision

I have developed a binary classifier using LightGBM, where I've primarily used the AUC metric due to its simplicity, ease of use, and interpretability.

Recently, I've taken an interest in utilizing the mean average precision-k (MAP@k) metric, and I understand that LightGBM offers two variants for this particular metric: `map_eval_at` and `map_at`.

Unfortunately, it's unclear to me what differentiates these two metrics, and which one might be more applicable to a binary classification task. There is not much information about this, all I found is that `map_eval_at` takes into account the order of the predictions while `map_at` doesn't.

What does this distinction imply? The classification task in my project involves predicting therapeutic responses, with outcomes being either response or no response, and a classification threshold of 0.5. Is prediction order significant in this context? I find this quite perplexing.